# Constructor initialization order and reference passing

Tags: c++, constructor

Hi I have a question about the constructor initialization order. Given below

```
struct B {}
struct A
{
    B& b;
    A(B& b) : b(b) {}
}
struct C
{
    B b;
    A a;
    C() : b(),a(b) {}
}
struct D
{
    A a;
    B b;
    D() : a(b),b() {}
}
```

I know that C is valid as b gets initialized before a. But what about D? b wouldn't have been constructed yet, but the address should already be known, so it should be safe?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're both valid because A doesn't call into B at all. If A accessed a data member or member function of B, then that would be invalid. In the existing case of A, it's impossible to produce an *invalid* example.

Comment: If you want to create an invalid example, change `A::b` from a reference to an object. Creating a `D` will then involve an invalid copy of an uninitialised object.

Answer (score 0):

just a sample to show you when stuff happens

```
struct B {
    B() {
        print("struct B / constructor B", 1);
    }
};
struct A
{
    B& b;
    A(B& b) : b(b) {
        print("struct A / constructor with B", 1);
    };

};
struct C
{
    B b;
    A a;
    C() : b(),a(b) {
        print("struct C / constructor C", 1);
    };
    void dummy()
    {
        print("dummy",1);
    }
};
struct D
{
    A a;
    B b;
    D() : a(b),b() {

        print("struct D / constructor D", 1);
    };
    void dummy()
    {
        print("dummy",1);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    D dTest;
    dTest.dummy();

    C cTest;
    cTest.dummy();

}
```

--- output

```
struct A / constructor with B
struct B / constructor B
struct D / constructor D
dummy
struct B / constructor B
struct A / constructor with B
struct C / constructor C
dummy
```

Comment: when you change in struct D the order of A and B then you get a different output, independent of the call order at the constructor...